# Product Categorization, Viewing and adding to Menu in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I'm searching for ideas to do the following in Drupal-7:

1- Create **product categories** (Main category, and sub categories, and products itself...)

ex. **Cars**, Motor Cycles ... are Main categories of products,
    Audi, Toyota ... are subcategories of a **Cars** main category,
    Audi A8 ... is the corresponding product.

2- **Dynamically** add the **Main categories** under a **menu** item.

3- **Main category** item when clicked view a **page of a related Sub-categories**.

4- **Sub-Category** item when clicked view a **gallery of images of related products**.

I've tried to work with content types and "Node Reference", and view it conditionally using "Views", or working with Taxonomy. But I think I need to integrate those solutions all to reach what I really want.

What steps should I follow using drupal modules, or **Will it need a custom module?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The use case you have mentioned is imo best suited for Taxonomy.
Its in core.

**For Point #1:**
Create a Taxonomy vocabulary called "Product Categories".
Then add terms "Cars", "Motor Cycles", etc to it.
Now create child terms under Car's term, called Audi, Tayota etc.

After configuring your taxonomy. Add a term reference field to your content type ( say vehicle). Now you can associate your nodes with the taxonomy terms while creating Vehicle contents.

This approach is very flexible cause the relation hierarchy is maintained in a seperate interface and is not hardcoded into each nodes. Also you can have multiple term to which a particular vehicle belongs to. Like a vehicle can be in SUV subterm, as well as Cars.

I suggest using Taxonomy cause, it will handle the hierarchy ( the tree structure ) much better than node references. And you can leverage that while making views.

**For Point #2:**
You can us Taxonomy Menu ( a contributed Module ) to create teh menu item. Otherwise a view with display type Html List can also be used to list the terms ( and display count as well.. like Cars(36), Motor Cycles(22) ... and so on.

**For Point #3:**
Taxonomy automatically provides you pages to display content belonging to certain terms. To show related content you can leverage the help of Views. For example 
Arguments -> Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth) will help you grab all the nodes belonging to child terms. Now i understand you dont want to show nodes, but Term.. this could be done by configuring field appropriately to show just the term name in views.

[You may find the view export given in here very helpful](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms).

**For Point #4:**
You get a default page for taxonomy term where it shows teaser of associated nodes. If that is not enough for your gallery, you can create a view for sub categories yourself, which takes term-id as argument.